# I can't load any web page by browsers in linux

Tags: linux, browser, debian

I can't load any webpage in browsers (mozilla and chrome).
Also i can't execute `sudo apt update` command, because my file  `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` locked by `process 917`.

But my computer has internet, because messengers like telegram is working.
And i can execute command `ping -c5 8.8.8.8` and it loads packages fine.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with `apt`, you likely have another instance of `apt` running somewhere. You really don't want doing multiple operations on your system's packages at the same time so `apt` automatically sets a lock file (`/var/lib/apt/lists/lock`) to avoid that.

tl.dr. find the other running instance of `apt` and kill it if appropriate. If you cant find any (can happen sometimes), delete the `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` file yourself (please see https://askubuntu.com/a/335801).